# Screen formatted text pane in PowerPoint

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

I am building a PowerPoint to train technicians on reading a series of log files.  They are plain text, with very long lines and best viewed without word wrap.  I would like to retain the aesthetic of the log file in my examples that I will be using in the slides.  I am looking to find a way to add a text pane into a PowerPoint slide that includes scroll bars and maintains screen formatting or web formatting instead of using page formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Add an ActiveX text box control, right click it and choose Properties.
Set the following at a minimum:

```
EnterKeyBehavior = True
MultiLine = True
ScrollBars = 3 - fmScrollBarsBoth
WordWrap = False
```

You may also want to set the font to e.g. Courier

Then press F5 to start the slide show and paste in the text you want to include in the textbox. Once pasted in, it'll stay there unless you edit it, which you can also do during the show; that might make this even more useful. You can also select text to highlight it.